# Finding the distribution law

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Throwing a cube twice,
let $X$ be the sum of the two throws

> Find the distribution law

My attempt
$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
 &2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12 \\
\hline
\text{P}_\text{X}(x) & 1/12 & 1/12 & 1/12&1/12&1/12&1/12&1/12&1/12&1/12&1/12&1/12 \\
\end{array}
$$

But shouldn't the sum be $1$? Currently the sum is $11/12$

Comment: The sum must be 1. It could just be a mistake. The sample space has 36 possible outcomes not 12, if you write them down all, you will be able to see your mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The probabilities are not equal. Have a look at the following table.
$$
\left.\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5& 6\\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5& 6& 7 \\\hline 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7& 8\\\hline 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8& 9\\\hline 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9& 10\\\hline 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10& 11\\\hline 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11& 12\end{array}\right.
$$
It is easy to tell various probabilities of the outcomes of this experiment using the table above. For example, the probability that we get $7$ is $6/36=1/6$.

Comment: Now all is clear, thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

\begin{array}{c|lcr}
 &2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12 \\
\hline
\text{P}_\text{X}(x) & 1/36 & 2/36 & 3/36&4/36&5/36&6/36&5/36&4/36&3/36&2/36&1/36 \\
\end{array}

Now the sum is $1$.

Answer (score 2):

What you've tried is wrong:

You can get $2$ just getting a one in each die (1+1), so the probability is $\frac{1}{6} \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{36}$. Instead, you have more options to get $5$ (1+4,2+3,3+2,4+1), giving you a total probability of $\frac{2}{18}$

Doing this process for all the numbers you get the correct result.

Comment: +1 for the heck of it. Are you a teacher in the US? I'm just asking since the claim "you're close to the right result" just seems ... so wrong. The only thing the OP has right are the types of possible outcomes for $X$. He's essentially as far from being right as you can possibly be if you can add and have seen a distribution table before. He gets many points for checking his answer of course, but that still doesn't get to being close to the right result..

Comment: @DRF No, not at all. You're completely right, I've edited my post to reflect that the original way of thinking of the OP wasn't right. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the final distribution should sum to one. I recommend drawing a 6x6 table and fill in the intersections with the sum of the two values. Then count up all the squares that sum to 2 for example and divide that by 36. Do that for each sum. If that is what you did, then you might have made a small mistake.